# jQuery Mobile / Template / dynamic element events

Tags: jquery, html, templates, jquery-mobile

this is my first time posting on stackoverflow so I apologize in advance for not really getting this post right. My issue is deleting a DIV which is create dynamically through a template. i have tried using .on but this does not work. I can delete the first div which loads with the page, but ones added later will not delete(I have an alert inserted to test now).

Here is my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>jQuery Mobile Test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script> 
<style>
</style> 
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" id="btnAddNewDate" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete">New Date</a>
    <h1>My Travel Log</h1>
    <button class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check">Save</button>
</div>

<div id="jqM" data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="a" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 data-position="inline">No Date Yet!          
            <button class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete del-div"> </button>
        </h3>
            <!--<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right"> </a>-->
            <!--<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right">Right</a>-->
            <!--<button class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete del-div"> </button>-->
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="div-template" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 id="h3Date"data-position="inline">${title}       
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete del-div"> </a>
        </h3>
        <p>${content}</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateDivs = [
        {title:"No Date Yet!", content:"some Content."}
    ]; 
    //$( "#myList li:first" ).clone().appendTo( "#myList" );
    $( "#btnAddNewDate" ).click(function () {
        $("#div-template").tmpl(dateDivs).appendTo("#jqM");
        $( "#jqM" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
        //$( "#div-template" ).clone().appendTo( "#jqM" );
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.del-div', function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });

    //$('#jqM').on( "click", ".del-div", function(){alert("delete");} );
    $(".del-div" ).click(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Why jQuery doesn`t trigger click event, but **i think that collapse component blocking your click event handler when you click collapse header.**

So, you can alternative mouse event like mousedown, mouseup.
I just tested below code, and it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>jQuery Mobile Test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" id="btnAddNewDate" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete">New Date</a>
    <h1>My Travel Log</h1>
    <button class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check">Save</button>
</div>

<div id="jqM" data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="a" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 data-position="inline">No Date Yet!
            <button class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete del-div"> </button>
        </h3>
        <!--<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right"> </a>-->
        <!--<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right">Right</a>-->
        <!--<button class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete del-div"> </button>-->
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="div-template" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 class="h3Date" data-position="inline">${title}
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete del-div"> </a>
        </h3>
        <p>${content}</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateDivs = [
        {title:"No Date Yet!", content:"some Content."}
    ];
    //$( "#myList li:first" ).clone().appendTo( "#myList" );
    $( "#btnAddNewDate" ).click(function () {
        $("#div-template").tmpl(dateDivs).appendTo("#jqM");
        $( "#jqM" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
        //$( "#div-template" ).clone().appendTo( "#jqM" );
    });

    $(document).on('mousedown', '.del-div', function () {
        $(this).closest('div.ui-collapsible').remove();
        $( "#jqM" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
    });


</script>
```

BTW, There are some another problem in your code.
h3 element in #div-template may cause duplicate id.
I changed that id attribute to class attribute.

Sorry for my poor English. I hope my answer was helpful.
Thank you!